# IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configuration root that contains on FileProvider.getUriForFile

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to share file from remote location, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/31AB-1310/Android/data/com.example.myapp/cache/EasyImage/a9c926ea-4dce-44b7-94e9-a5dca6b91a5d-450242437.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
    at pl.aprilapps.easyphotopicker.EasyImage.createCameraPictureFile(EasyImage.java:54)
    at pl.aprilapps.easyphotopicker.EasyImage.createChooserIntent(EasyImage.java:109)
```

My FileProvider code has the following manifest entry:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

My res/xml/filpaths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

My Activity.java file :

```
private void shareCurrentData(String filepath) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            File shareFile= new File(filepath);
            Uri shareUri =FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY,shareFile);
            //files.add(textUri);
            files.add(shareUri);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share using....."));
    }
}
```

I just cant understand what raises the exception because everything seems to fit.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for help. I tried using other way still showing same exception   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /D:/ptrut/Public/prt/2112/333/Attachment/Feedback Form_8412.xls

Answer (score 0):

```
/storage/31AB-1310/Android/data/com.example.myapp/cache/EasyImage/a9c926ea-4dce-44b7-94e9-a5dca6b91a5d-450242437.jpg
```

A path like that usually comes from removable storage. `FileProvider` does not support removable storage.

So, focus on ensuring that `filepath` is on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).